# Hide/Show Links in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to show 2 links - **Show and Hide**. When I click on Show, Show should be hidden and Hide should be visible and when I click on Hide, Hide should be hidden and Show should be visible. How can I achieve this in html?

Comment: You can achieve it alot of ways. What have you done?

Comment: You can do that by display property in style by giving "none" and "block". This is one of the easiest way and I hope you can do by yourself instead of exact code from us.

Comment: @NsDeep Next time you change an accepted answer to the jQuery one even when you haven't specified that you want to use that library, be so kind and add a jQuery tag to the Q. It is a standard here to add jQuery tag if you are interested in using jQuery library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with jquery in the head

```
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

and an id for each button

```
<input type='button' id='show' value='Show' />
<input type='button' id='hide' value='Hide' />
```

you can do it something like *this untested code*...

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function(){
        $('#show').click(function(){
            $('#hide').hide()
        })
        $('#hide').click(function(){
            $('#show').hide()
        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: You have implemented "standard" behaviour, but it looks like NsDeep asked for the unusual one.

Comment: I think I was a little confused. I actually want to show tool-tip help content when Show is pressed and hide it when Hide link is clicked. I want the user to know if he has pressed Hide/Show. Which can be shown by some toggle effect. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

Do you really only want to hide "hide" when "show" is clicked and vice versa? Because that is what you asked for, but it doesn't really sound as a "standard" (toggle) behaviour.

But here it is:

See **[this](http://jsbin.com/ugofed/edit#javascript,html,live)** snippet.

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" id="show">SHOW</a>
<a href="#" id="hide">HIDE</a>
```

**JS:**

```
var showElem = document.getElementById("show");
var hideElem = document.getElementById("hide");

showElem.onclick = function() {
   hideElem.style.display = 'none';
}

hideElem .onclick = function() {
   showElem.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Instead of `.style.display = 'none';` you can use `.style.visibility = 'hidden'` which will still hide the link, but there will be empty space instead of it and it won't really completely dissapear (see **[this](http://jsbin.com/eyazig/edit#javascript,html,live)** snippet).

**Update:** Based on discussion in the comments section new simple example was created (see [this](http://jsbin.com/ugofed/5/edit)) that have more "standard" behaviour. In case the page is expected to be heavy on effects or other javascript functionality (like Ajax) I would recommend to use 3rd party library like jQuery to simplify the implementation - see answer by *Billy Moon*.

Comment: And also I'm refreshing the page after I click on the link for some backend processing. Will the functionality still be there?

Comment: I think I was a little confused. I actually want to show tool-tip help content when Show is pressed and hide it when Hide link is clicked. I want the user to know if he has pressed Hide/Show. Which can be shown by some toggle effect. How can this be done?

Comment: @NsDeep: Do you mean something like **[this](http://jsbin.com/ugofed/4/edit)**? If you want use of effects it is a good idea to use library for that (like jQuery).

Comment: @ dzejkej: Yes thats what I want. But not exactly a <div>. Its just the title attribute which I'm using. the content within title will be retrieved from my action class(I'm using Struts 2). this is the code for the same:  <s:textfield key="global.username" name="username" maxlength="50"
        title="%{strDescription}" />                            To retrieve/hide the title content I'll be calling the method when I either click on Hide/Show link. So the page is getting refreshed and the changes made (visible/Hidden) wont be retained. :(

Comment: @NsDeep Cannot you use AJAX to retrieve that data, so you don't have to refresh the page? It is also faster and state of the page remains intact.

Comment: @ dzejkej: Can you tell me how? I need to fetch the description from the ehcache (second level cache).

Comment: @NsDeep Please search this site (terms like `ajax struts2 jquery` or similar) and if unsuccessful then create a new question. This is out of scope of this question and having it in separate one will help other people when searching for solution, etc. You should also accept an answer if it is answering what you asked for in a question :). See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).